# How to select distinct DATE in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to select distinct date but its not working and duplicated

This is the SELECT I tried it and its working in SQL Server :

```
SELECT DISTINCT date 
FROM STATISTICS_DAILY 
WHERE hospital_no = 1
```

This is the output I get:

```
2023-06-06 00:00:00.000
2023-06-07 00:00:00.000
2023-06-08 00:00:00.000
2023-06-08 15:21:46.000
2023-06-09 00:00:00.000
2023-06-10 00:00:00.000
```

But in ASP.NET MVC, how to get same result this is `Index` controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     int HospitalId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["HospitalID"]);

     var sTATISTICS_DAILY = db.STATISTICS_DAILY
                              .Where(x => x.hospital_no == HospitalId)
                              .OrderBy(d => d.DATE)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
     return View(sTATISTICS_DAILY.ToList());
 }
```

This is the view markup :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.STATISTICS_DAILY>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATE)
        </th>
       
    
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATE)
        </td>
       
     
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

but its not distinct this is the output

how to solve it and select distinct date one time only ?
[image]

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is an aggregation operation in disguise, whereas your Linq query doesn't perform any aggregation: the `.Distinct()` step returns distinct outputs, which in this case are _not_ `DateTime` values but actually objects representing source rows, which are _by nature_ distinct (as objects in-memory tend to be), hence why it isn't filtering.

Comment: @Dai there is no way to to perform distinct for Date like SQL server or any other way ?

Comment: BTW, you cannot meaningfully display distinct date values _and also_ map them to their source rows: if multiple rows have ther same `DATE` column value then which `.id` should be used for those links in the Edit/Details/Delete column? I think you need to rethink what it is you're trying to do here...

Comment: @Dai In Edit and Details I select the data for this date and loop it to show all date data

Comment: I'm talking about the `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Linq query, as-is, doesn't actually filter rows by any single distinct column value: in your case the `.Distinct()` step returns distinct outputs, which in this case are *not* `DateTime` values but actually objects representing source rows, which are *by nature* distinct (as objects in-memory tend to be), hence why it isn't filtering.

The solution is to change your query to first extract the `date` value (which will turn your query into `IQueryable<DateTime>` instead of `IQueryable<STATISTICS_DAILY>`; also, because `.Distinct()` is a *reduction* operation you will lose access to the other columns in `STATISTICS_DAILY`, which  is something I assume you're already familiar with:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    Int32 hospitalId = Convert.ToInt32( this.Session["HospitalID"] ); // Avoid using Session-state btw.
    List<DateTime> values = await this.db.STATISTICS_DAILY
        .Where( s => s.hospital_no == hospitalId )
        .Select( s => s.DATE )
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy( dt => dt )
        .ToListAsync( cancellationToken );

     return this.View( values );
}
```

You'll need to change your Razor `.cshtml` file's `@model` to `List<DateTime>` btw too.

Comment: I copy the complete action and added using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;  but show error cannot implicitly convert type syste.collection.genericlist to system.datetime on List<DateTime>

Comment: You haven't posted the full error message there so I cannot be sure what the problem is exactly, but it looks like it might be due to nullability (i.e. `List<DateTime>` vs `List<DateTime?>`) - so is the `s.DATE` column `NULL` or `NOT NULL`? If so, then you need to think about how you want to handle `NULL` entries in that column, which is up to you because that's a business/domain question, not a technical question.

Comment: the full error "cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.list<System.DateTime?> to System.Collection.Generic.List<System.DateTime>"     the DATE column I changed it to NOT NULL some rows was null before I deleted it

Comment: now no error but what I need to change in Razor also  the model first line and DateTime columns to List <DateTime>   ? thank you so much

Comment: I updated the view @model List<warehouse.Models.STATISTICS_DAILY>  but when run it show this error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[warehouse.Models.STATISTICS_DAILY]'

Comment: can you sir help me in this question thank you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445501/how-can-i-select-drop-down-list-data-depends-on-condition

Comment: @ZiadAdnan I'm sorry but I'm not really able to assist you further.

Comment: sorry for that and thank you so much