# How can I select drop down list data depends on condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tests drop down list.

How can I select the tests in drop down list where `DEPT_ID = 12`?

I have the table includes the following columns:

```
DEPT_ID TEST_D 
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        4
2        5
2        6
3        7
4        8
5        9
12       50
12       51
12       52 
12       53
```

This is GET Index and Create controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.TEST_ID = new SelectList(db.LabTests, "TestId", "TestName");
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var iNFECTION_DISEASE = db.INFECTION_DISEASE.Where(d=>d.DEPT_ID==12).Include(i => i.Department).Include(i => i.Hospital).Include(i => i.LabTest).Include(i => i.sys_users);
    return View(iNFECTION_DISEASE.ToList());
}
```

This is `TEST_ID` `.cshtml` part of view

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TEST_ID, "TEST_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TEST_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TEST_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the tables declaration :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INFECTION_DISEASE](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DEPT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TEST_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TOTAL_TESTS] [int] NULL,
    [NEGATIVE] [int] NULL,
    [POSITIVE] [int] NULL,
    [NATIONALITY] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [REGION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [hospital_no] [int] NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LabTests](
    [TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Dept_id] [int] NULL)
```

How can I select tests in drop down list where `DEPT_ID = 12` only?

Comment: Do you mean make the `DEPT_ID = 12` as the default selection?

Comment: @Jackdaw not the default selection only select test_id where dept_id = 12    or  another way if can select test_id where test_id in (50,51,52,53) I need it like this

Comment: @ZiadL: How your table is declared? Are your using the Entity Framework ORM?

Comment: @Jackdaw I added the tables declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question above does not contain all related parts of code. But I suppose it should be like the following:

```cs
var tests = db.LabTests.Where(lt => lt.DEPT_ID == 12).Select(t => t.Test).ToList();
ViewBag.TEST_ID = new SelectList(tests, "TestId", "TestName");
```

Comment: I changed this Select(t => t.TestId) and when click on CREATE it show this error DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'TestId'.

Comment: thank you so much its working I removed the part  .Select(t => t.Test) and it get the tests list where dept_id = 12 :)